# JS Global variable to local equivalent

Tags: javascript, optimization, global-variables, local-variables

Simple question - is it worth to create local equivalents of global variables inside of functions if we make a lot of actions on them?

```
var global = $(elements);

function foo(){
    var local = global;
    // lots of actions on local
}

function foo2(){
    // lots of actions on global
}
```

As far as I know, refering to global variables forces script to access the global scope and get values from them. I just wonder if is it worth to make an equivalents of global inside of functions which uses them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It helps to create a local copy because variable resolution starts at the most local and goes toward looking in the global namespace, making it slower.

Much slower in certain older browsers.

Here is a benchmark: http://jsperf.com/global/25

#### Update:

Added an updated version with another test case that in theory shows that most of the performance impact comes from going up the scope chain.

http://jsperf.com/global/30

Comment: "Much slower in certain older, browsers." - do you have any specific benchmark in mind? I am interested...

Comment: "jQuery uses a cache mechanism" - no, it doesn't, and it can't because then it would miss any changes.

Comment: It does. It caches every function call with the same parameters in a `data` section.

Comment: For benchmarks, I haven't the link to one but I saw it on jsPerf some time ago.

Comment: Selectors are not cached, definitely. As for data, it's not really caching, but rather a piece of storage that is initialised from data attributes. Data attributes are never written to through `$().data`.

Comment: Added a link to the benchmarak

Comment: You make it sound like the results of selection (`$(...)`) are cached. They are not, and they can't be.

Comment: Very interesting benchmark. Any idea why is this so? Could it be because the compiler cannot to as many optimisations? I suspect dead code elimination, but assigning the final result to a global variable doesn't change the result.

Comment: It seems I was wrong about the caching part. My results were due to an extension. Sorry. About the speed difference I think it is because the function first scans for the variable in the `local scope`, than go up the `scope chain` until it finds the variable or reaches the `global scope`.

Comment: Still... 50% speed difference? Also, I would expect V8 to perform this kind of caching itself.

Comment: I would too. I added another test case. It seems most of the performance cost comes from the scope chain call (unless i failed in coding the test XD)

Comment: Well, I'd like to see the other case too. Hope someone will extend this anwser. However thanks for link to benchmark. If this method gives even a smallest performance boost it is worth it's effort, escpecially if youre targeting mobile devices. Thanks.

Comment: Updated with the other test case (you can see all versions at the bottom of that page).

Answer (score 0):

You don't have nothing to worry about.
Usually using global variables is discouraged because can make you code harder to mantain.
The performance impact of a global variable is very little.